# YouTube videos are glitchy, pixelize, etc

Tags: video, youtube

From a few months I've had a problem with videos on YouTube (it doesn’t matter from quality), sometimes in Facebook also. I don't know how to describe it, but it starts to pixelize like on the top of the screen and sometimes in the middle like it tries to skip some of the frames. The video is going smoothly, not like in the screenshot. 2-3 months ago everything was fine. The web browser that I use is Firefox 61.01.1 (64-bit).

Results of `lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3` :

```
neno@neno-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15IBR:~$ lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b1] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3904]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:13.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22a3] (rev 21)
```

Laptop specs:

[image]

Comment: Hi neno! Welcome to askUbuntu! Please add some more information  about your problem. E.g. the Ubuntu version  you are using, what player are you using and  on which browser. And it is helpful if you add the output (as plain text) of  the following command to your original post: `lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3`. If you have problems formatting your post, read: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: Can you please check if Flash Player is enabled in your web browser and, if yes, disable it, reload the web page with the video and try to play it back again? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I've switch of Shockwave Flash from Firefox ,it a little bit better but still... :(